# Not working: find -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c "...."

Tags: bash, find, xargs

O/S = RHEL 7.2

As you would expect, the first two lines below print "dbg' followed by all the files immediately under /home/mydir.  But if I use -print0 and xargs -0 as shown in the second two lines, the first file in the directory is skipped.  I tried changing the echo to 
    echo dbg "$0" $@"
This works as long as there are files in the subdirectory.  On an empty subdirectory, $0 returns "bash".

```
# This works
dir=/home/mydir
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | xargs  bash -c '/bin/echo dbg "$@"'  

# This skips the first file
dir=/home/mydir
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c '/bin/echo dbg "$@"'
```

Comment: Works exactly like expected (Linux Mint 17.3, GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)). Both lines give the same output.

Comment: Good to know.  I'm testing on RHEL 7.2.  I have edited the question to include, that, along with some corrections about the actual behavior I am seeing.

Comment: You don't need `xargs`: `find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c '/bin/echo dbg "$@"' _ {} \;`. In fact you don't even need `bash`  at all: `find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec /bin/echo dbg {} \;`

Comment: Good points, both.  I should have indicated that this was a simplified example meant to isolate the problem.  In real life, I am calling a user-defined bash function -- which is why I need to call bash.  And I don't want to use `find -exec`, since I am going to be calling the function hundreds of thousands of times.  Given the nature of the utilities inside my function (e.g. setfacl), using xargs saves me huge amounts of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `bash -c 'command' arg0 arg1 arg2 …`, the argument represented as `arg0` is treated as `$0`, the name of the script (and not part of `"$@"`, therefore).

You could demonstrate with:

```
$ bash -c 'echo dbg "$@"' a b c
dbg b c
$ bash -c 'echo dbg "$@"' name a b c
dbg a b c
$ bash -c 'echo dbg [$0] "$@"' name a b c
dbg [name] a b c
$
```

Use:

```
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c '/bin/echo dbg "$@"' name
```

Comment: Thank you; I was coming around to something like this; I finally understand the use of that placeholder I have seen mentioned elsewhere.  I'm still confused by the differences between using -print and -print0, but once everything is working I will revisit that.  I will post here if I learn anything interesting.

Comment: To see the benefit of `-print0` and `-0`, you'll need to have file names with spaces or similar in them, and a way to detect argument boundaries properly (`"$@"` is part of the answer, but `echo` probably isn't; maybe use `printf "[%s]\n"` instead of `echo`).  Similarly with file names containing newlines, tabs, and other odd-ball characters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation -- but I guess I wasn't clear.  I was referring back to the original problem statement, in which -print and -print0 behaved differently.   Either I am failing to understand something basic, or I made a fundamental error in my testing.  (I can't discount the latter till I go back and re-test everything.  Since I didn't understand what was going on, I cannot swear I didn't do something stupid in my testing.)

Comment: By default, `xargs` runs the command once, even if there are no files.  With GNU `xargs`, you can suppress that with `-r` (or `--no-run-if-empty`).  If you don't specify an `arg0` because there are no files, then the name used is `bash` after all.  A single file would be used as `arg0`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan!  I never thought to look for something like -r.  Makes sense, though, and cleans up other aspects of my code.  Much obliged.